# Pass by reference when using splat operator (...)

Tags: php, operators, pass-by-reference

I have two functions. One of them receive and modify some values in an array that is passed by reference.

```php
function dostuff ($param1, $param2, &$arr) {
    //...
    //add new elements to $arr
}
```

The other, which is a method in a class, that wraps the first one:

```php
class Wrapper
{
    public function foo (...$args) {
        return dostuff(...$args);
    }
}
```

However, if I pass the array to 'foo', the array stays unchanged.
I've tried to declare `foo(... &$args)` with an `&` but this led to an syntax error.

Is there a way to pass arguments by reference when using splat operator in PHP?

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie like this: https://3v4l.org/1GKCh

Comment: You can do it like this: https://3v4l.org/nKUlS  Or https://3v4l.org/4kg0u

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie even its defined outside class scope, it can be modified. That is why we have the last parameter as a reference. Example: https://3v4l.org/49XlX

Comment: I had to call `dostuff` instead of `foo`

Comment: oh, got it. then you can go with the answer posted below

Comment: It is almost there. The issue with the answer bellow is that the first and second parameter only worked because he assigned the first and second parameters to variables (which modified the original signature). In the real scenario I couldn't do this as the original function is part of an external package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PHP 8.x Versions https://3v4l.org/9ivmL

Do it like this:

```
<?php

class Wrapper
{
    public function foo (&...$args) {
        return $this->dostuff(...$args);
    }

    public function dostuff($param1, $param2, &$arr) {
        $arr[] = $param1;
        $arr[] = $param2;

        return count($arr);
    }
}


$values = [1,2];
$a=3;
$b=4;
$obj = new Wrapper();
#all parameter must be variables here because there are by ref now
$count = $obj->foo($a,$b, $values);

echo "Elements count: $count\r\n";
print_r($values); //Expected [1,2,3,4]
```

Output

```
Elements count: 4
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php  Example #13

Comment: Hi. This threw me an fatal error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Wrapper::foo(): Argument #1 cannot be passed by reference`

Comment: @CarlosCarucce This is tested with php 8.x   https://3v4l.org/9ivmL

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie Its an updated version of the OP Code https://3v4l.org/1GKCh

Comment: Yes. But in reality this is used in a facade class for a routing system. I just got like this for simplicity sake

Comment: @CarlosCarucce And i just showed you were the `&` must be placed, not `foo(... &$args)`, valid is  `foo(&...$args)`.

Comment: Still the same. See this: https://3v4l.org/4rV2I

Comment: @CarlosCarucce I added an comment in my code above. If you use `by ref` all parameter must be a variable like  `$a` not a value like `3`

Comment: Yes. That is why I did not accept your answer yet. This would modify the method signature.  In the real world project, "dostuff" is part of an external package.

Comment: @CarlosCarucce _This would modify the method signature_ no it does not. You are just using variables instead of values to _call_ the method _foo()_. And "dostuff" is unchanged in my answer. I did what you did, fixing `foo()` nothing more. And since now `foo()` takes all parameter by ref, regardless of using _dostuff()_ within _foo()_, you have to use variables for all parameters when calling _foo()_.

Comment: Got it. You're right